# Cisco 2960-x doesn't ping default-gateway and creates duplicate packets

Tags: cisco, switch, ping, gateway, packets

I need someone's help

I have 3 Cisco 2960-X distribution switches stacked (1 master, 2 slaves),

Once a week, our monitoring system alert us that the switch is down, until we reboot it.

I ping/telnet the management interface (from the same VLAN).
But the monitoring server that is on another VLAN doesn't ping or access the switch. The reason is that the switch does not either ping or access the router (it's ip default-gateway).

Also, when the switch starts getting crazy, I have got (DUP!) duplicate packets returned by ping commands to some IPs.
Sometimes it says DUP!, and sometimes it doesn't

I tried a shut/no shut but only a reboot resolves the issue, and next week, the problem will occur again.

Does anyone encounter this problem ?? Thank's

Comment: I suggest creating a Cisco TAC case as this clearly sounds like a bug.

Comment: Didn't know about Cisco TAC, I will try.
Thank you

Comment: If you didn't know about it, I assume your company did not buy the SmartNet contracts? If that case you can't get assistance from Cisco TAC as far as I know.

Comment: You are right, we don't have any "SmartNet" contract. I tried to open a ticket but I can't. Probably going to find out on a Cisco forum..

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug. [Cisco Bug: CSCuv80924 - Packet is duplicated during link failover of EC over stack switch - Products: Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Series Switches](https://quickview.cloudapps.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCuv80924).